# Enabling clean method chaining of async functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await

I am trying to achieve clean method chaining of async functions in Typescript by making them `return this`.

Here is my class:

```
class PaymentPage {

  async enterCreditCardMainDetails() {
    await t.typeText(this.someField, 'someText');
    return this;
  }

  async enterCreditCardAdditionalDetails() {
    await t.typeText(this.someField, 'someText');
    return this;
  }
}
```

Obviously, when I try to call those methods using method chaining:

```
  async test() {
    await new PaymentPage()
      .enterCreditCardMainDetails()
      .enterCreditCardAdditionalDetails()
      .clickAddNewCardButton();
  }
```

I am getting error: `TS2339: Property 'enterCreditCardAdditionalDetails' does not exist on type 'Promise<PaymentPage>'.`

So the only workaround I found is to wrap each method call with `await`, however the result is not super clean (especially when chaining a lot of methods):

```
await (await (await new PaymentPage()
      .enterCreditCardMainDetails())
      .enterCreditCardAdditionalDetails())
      .clickAddNewCardButton();
  }
```

Is there a way to implement method chaining in a more clean and readable way, for example by somehow modifying `return this` value?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
async test() {
  const paymentPage = await new PaymentPage();
  await paymentPage.enterCreditCardMainDetails();
  await paymentPage.enterCreditCardAdditionalDetails();
  await paymentPage.clickAddNewCardButton();
}
```

Comment: That's actually what we are doing right now.
But it is not convenient when you call methods from different classes. That is why we want to implement method chaining flow and not be concerned of which page should we initialize next to call next method. This will be handled by all methods returning either `return this` or `return new Page()`

Comment: Being explicit is more important than convenience. If you really want to do chaining with promise-based functions, you might need to implement your own A+ promises, but you're going down a rabbithole.